# How do you use a keyboard shortcut that requires ctrl-\ when you have to use multiple keys to type an \?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts

Default in most terminal you can press <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>\</kbd> to send a SIGQUIT signal to the process.

However on my keyboard to type a backslash, you have to do it like this: <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>7</kbd>

Doing <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>7</kbd> doesn't work, so how should I do the keyboard shortcut?

Comment: Can you not rebind the shortcut to be something you can type simply?

Comment: What keyboard is that?

Comment: @week Danish OSX keyboard.

Answer (score 9):

I had to figure out the exact same thing today, with a German keyboard and in Ubuntu. So I've come up with the script below. Finding the right key still needs trial and error, but it's pretty simple that way.

For the record, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>4</kbd> did the trick in my case.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/bash

# Shows character codes while typing. More to the point, it also captures signals.

# Trap function
sig() {
    printf '\t\t\t%s\t(re-enabled now, works next time)\n' "$1"
    # A trap disables itself after being called once.
    trap - $1
}

# Setting traps for all signals
mapfile -t signals < <(trap -l | grep -Eo SIG[-+A-Z0-9]+)

for signal in "${signals[@]}"; do
    trap "sig $signal" "$signal"
done

# Display characters
printf "Start typing to examine characters and signals. Exit with Ctrl-C (twice).\n\n"
printf "Char\tDec\t Hex\tSignal\n"

while IFS= read -rN 1 char; do 
    LC_CTYPE=C printf '\t%3d\t0x%02X\n' "'$char" "'$char"
done
```

Comment: Thanks for posting, ctrl+4 works for me on ubuntu with a german keyboard as well.

Comment: Ctrl-4 worked for me with Swedish layout as well, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I don’t know how you can type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>,
but I can give you an alternative way to generate SIGQUIT from the keyboard. 
Find a character that you can type as a simple key combination. 
This probably needs to map to a (single) ASCII character (i.e., a single byte);
e.g., <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>. 
Then type

```
stty quit ^A
```

That can be either
<kbd>s</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>y</kbd> <kbd>q</kbd><kbd>u</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>t</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>
(if you get an error message, try typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>
before the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>)
or literally
<kbd>s</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>q</kbd><kbd>u</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>^</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>
(if you get an error message, try putting the <kbd>^</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> in quotes). 
Then type a command like `sleep 9`,
press your key combination (i.e., <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>),
and see whether the program quits
as you would expect for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>.

If you find a combination that works, put it (the `stty quit` command)
into your `.login`, `.profile`, `.bashrc`,
or whatever initialization command file you use.

Answer (score 2):

I had almost the same problem with a french "**azerty**" keyboard.

To get the backslash character `\`, I have to press <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>/</kbd>.

But pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>/</kbd> does not send any signal, it just inserts a dot `.` in the Terminal.

I found that pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>`</kbd> (the backtick or backquote key) does send the `SIGQUIT` signal:

```
$ sleep 9
^\Quit: 3
```

Pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>`</kbd> also works.

Note that, on a french keyboard, "shifting" the backtick character (i.e. pressing <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>`</kbd>) produces the Pound sign <kbd>£</kbd>.

You can get the list of all signals with the `kill -l` command:

```
$ kill -l
 1) SIGHUP       2) SIGINT       3) SIGQUIT  4) SIGILL
 5) SIGTRAP      6) SIGABRT      7) SIGEMT   8) SIGFPE
 9) SIGKILL     10) SIGBUS      11) SIGSEGV 12) SIGSYS
13) SIGPIPE     14) SIGALRM     15) SIGTERM 16) SIGURG
17) SIGSTOP     18) SIGTSTP     19) SIGCONT 20) SIGCHLD
21) SIGTTIN     22) SIGTTOU     23) SIGIO   24) SIGXCPU
25) SIGXFSZ     26) SIGVTALRM   27) SIGPROF 28) SIGWINCH
29) SIGINFO     30) SIGUSR1     31) SIGUSR2
```

Comment: Thanks, `ctrl + \`` is the only way to exit an Elixir shell with only one shortcut on a french MacOS keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

With my German keyboard, <kbd>ctr</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> sends a <kbd>ctr</kbd> <kbd>\</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried mapping a different key to `^\`?

For instance (in macOS terminal):

Go to “Terminal -> Preferences -> Settings -> Keyboard”, click the `+` and map something like <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>f4</kbd> to `\034`.

Comment: <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>4</kbd> just results in the 4 being typed.

Comment: kbd tag doesn't work in the comments. use the backquote instead. `Ctrl` + `4`

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>\</kbd> is likely to generate ASCII code 28.  Try doing something else that sends ASCII code 28.

For instance, maybe try this: hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd>, and then pressing <kbd>2</kbd> on the numpad, and then <kbd>8</kbd> on the numpad, and then releasing the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key.  (Granted, if you have troubles hitting backslash, maybe you have troubles using numpad keys.)  I don't have a Mac by me, but that works on many Unix-ish systems (and DOS/Microsoft Windows), so may be worth giving a shot.

If you are interacting with a remote system, you could put the character in a file and then some terminal software would let you use an "ASCII upload" to send the keystroke.

Another possible resource: [AppleScript: sending keys for OSX](http://macbiblioblog.blogspot.com/2014/12/key-codes-for-function-and-special-keys.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a Danish keyboard layout and I got it to work in Ubuntu with using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>><\</kbd> (the key next to <kbd>Left Shift</kbd>).

This sends a SIGQUIT to the active program:

`^\[1]    398660 quit (core dumped)`