# How to use a keyboard shortcut that requires ctrl-shift-\ when \ requires multiple keys under windows 11?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts

On my (German) keyboard, to type a backslash, I have to do it like this: <kbd>ALT GR</kbd> <kbd>ß</kbd>.

Adding <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> for the mentioned shortcut does not work, it just outputs a `ß` so how should I do the keyboard shortcut?

Detail: my keyboard does not have a right <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key, only one at the left.

(shortcut from: outline documentation system, for: code block)

( There is already [How do you use a keyboard shortcut that requires ctrl-\ when you have to use multiple keys to type an \?](https://superuser.com/questions/506061/how-do-you-use-a-keyboard-shortcut-that-requires-ctrl-when-you-have-to-use-mul), but it is tagged macos and none of the solutions worked for me )

Comment: Often just sending the correct 'key position' as English works [though not always]. Presumably you have an ISO keyboard, so try Ctrl/Shift/ key between Shift & Y [seems to be labelled > <  | on a picture google found] Might also be worth trying the key left of 1, just in case someone mapped it more like ANSI [US].

Comment: If you cannot change the keyboard shortcut keys in the application, then you might try a third-party tool, such as Clavier+ or AutoHotkey to remap another key combination to *output* the key-code for Ctrl-Shifrt-\ .